# What does this mean - "I meant if you could provide us with your references."?

Tags: phrase-usage

I am actively interviewing for a job in USA and my recruiter asked me to send him some of my references. I did not understand what it meant and asked him do you mean to send email-ids of persons who can refer me and in response to that he said - "I meant if you could provide us with your references." What should I do? Should I share contact details of my references?

Comment: Yes, send two or three names of those who know your work, along with some way of contacting them: email addresses, phone numbers, or such. That is called providing references. It is not one specific format.

Comment: Make sure your references know that you're using them as references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone who was a hiring manager for many years, I would expect to see the reference's name, your relationship to him or her (previous supervisors are best), email address, and phone number. You should expect the recruiter or potential employers to contact those people directly with a list of questions. I would not expect that you would provide the information for your current supervisor. If possible, for your current job, I would recommend providing the name and contact information for a trusted peer.

Answer (score 1):

That is a roundabout way of saying

> I meant we want you to provide us with your references.

The "if you could" construction is less direct and therefore a bit gentler, less like a command.